# PHP возвращение произвольного количества параметров из объекта в виде массива. Аналог eval JavaScript. Есть такой в PHP?

Tags: php

Всем привет.
Мне нужно в вызываемом классе сформировать несколько переменных и вернуть их. В разных классах могут быть разные переменные. Можно и в ассоциативном массиве, но как восстановить параметры и их значение при получении ? Не хочу писать что-то наподобие

```
$name = $ar[i]['name']; 
$age = $ar[i]['age'].
```

В JS сделал бы что-то подобное в цикле:

```
eval(ar[i]['name'] +"=" ar[i]['value'])
```

Comment: не надо такое делать ни в js ни где либо еще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такая вещь как [list](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.list.php)

```
list($name, $age) = [ $ar[$i]['name'],  $ar[$i]['age']]
```

Также с 7.1.0 есть короткий синтаксис

```
[$name, $age] =  [ $ar[$i]['name'],  $ar[$i]['age']];
```

Можно написать ещё так:

```
list('name' => $name, 'age' => $age) = $ar[$i];
```

Имея ключа в массиве => имя новой переменной;

Comment: возможно ему для произвольного нужно что-то типа `$fields = array_flip(['name', 'age'])` и `$data = array_combine($arr[$i], $fields)`

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, идея понятна